# How to make Git file size checking faster?

Tags: bash, git, pre-commit-hook

I have a bash script that checks whether the files to be committed fit a size limitation. However, when there are a large number of files, the script can take a long time to complete, even if there are no files that exceed the limit.

Here is the original script:

```
result=0
for file in $( git diff-index --ignore-submodules=all --cached --diff-filter=ACMRTUXB --name-only HEAD )
do
    echo $file
    if [[ -f "$file" ]]
    then
        file_size=$( git cat-file -s :"$file" )
        if [ "$file_size" -gt  "$max_allowed_packed_size" ]
        then
            echo File $file is $(( $file_size / 2**20 )) MB after compressing, which is larger than our configured limit of $(( $max_allowed_packed_size / 2**20 )) MB.
            result=1
        fi
    fi
done
fi
exit $result
```

Do you have any idea to improve the performance of checking the staged files?

Comment: That's likely slow because of this: `git cat-file` why do this instead of using e.g. `wc -c` or `stat` ? Generally, this sounds like a solution to a problem that shouldn't exist so: why do this at all - what is the use case where large files are  unintentionally being added to the repo?

Comment: Read up on [`git cat-file --batch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file#Documentation/git-cat-file.txt---batch-check).

Comment: @AD7six This issue arises because we aim to prevent our colleagues from committing and pushing large files to our repositories. We have previously had instances where some team members used our repositories to share files that were irrelevant to the project and too large to be stored efficiently. Apart from that, we use Git LFS for large files that are necessary for the project.

Comment: I question how effective a pre-commit hook is going to be here. I say that because each user has to effectively opt-in to using a pre-commit hook so it cannot be enforced, and even if it's installed you can bypass it - the error message when a commit fails even includes the command to do so. If you want to _prevent_ this from occurring I'd recommend speaking to your colleagues :). Today that conversation is "why do you need to do that, let's find a better way" if you implement this question/answer it's "why aren't you using this pre-commit hook" (which is going to be much less productive).

Comment: If you do want to actually enforce this restriction, you need to do it in the [pre-receive hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#:~:text=pre%2D-,receive,-The%20first%20script) on the server

Answer (score 0):

1.Use Git LFS (Large File Storage): Git LFS is an open-source Git extension that replaces large files with text pointers. This allows Git to handle large files more efficiently, which can speed up file size checking.

2.Ignore large files: You can also speed up file size checking by ignoring large files that are not necessary for the repository. You can do this by creating a .gitignore file in the root directory of your repository and adding patterns for the files or file types you want to ignore.

3.Use shallow cloning: Shallow cloning means that you only clone a certain number of commit histories from the remote repository. This can significantly reduce the amount of data you need to download and check, and can speed up file size checking.

4.Use Git hooks: Git hooks are scripts that run automatically when certain Git events occur, such as a commit or push. You can use a Git hook to check the file size of new or modified files and reject them if they exceed a certain size limit. This can help prevent large files from being added to the repository in the first place, which can save time on file size checking.

5.Use a faster computer or network: If your computer or network is slow, file size checking will naturally be slower. Upgrading your computer or network can help speed up file size checking.

Answer (score -1):

```
$git config --global 
Install git-sizer
$git-sizer --help
$git status   #check status
```

Comment: `Install git-sizer` please explain your answer, as written that reads like: [how to draw an owl](https://seths.blog/2014/01/how-to-draw-an-owl/) :)

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?